# How to get the middle index of a array in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a bug getting the middle index of an array. Here's the array:

```
CountedArray = ["Jake","Jacob","Sam","Tom","Ben","Joe","Bob","Chen","sara","Simon"]
```

Comment: What’s the bug? As in what code are you using to find the middle index, and what is the problem you are having with it?

Comment: No problem just tried searching and found nothing

Comment: Please explain what _the middle index_ means. And showing your code, even if it may have some bugs, will help you to get more appropriate answers sooner. One more, your expected result for your example array also helps.

Comment: If an array has 2 elements, which one is the middle? What about arrays with 1 or 0 elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
let middle = CountedArray.count / 2
print(CountedArray[middle])
```

Comment: No need to check the count first. Both `0 / 2` and `1 / 2` will result in `0`. `let middle = array.count / 2` gives the same result.

Comment: It's worth noting that before using `middle` as a subscript, you need to ensure the array is not empty. If `CountedArray = []` the above will crash.

Answer (score 0):

What's about

```
let index = CountedArray.count == 0 ? 0 : (CountedArray.count / 2) - 1
```

Comment: This fails when the array is empty.

Comment: @rmaddy Then check if the array is empty or not. If you do not minus 1, you just get the length, not the index. See my edited

Answer (score -1):

Here are some concerns.

- If array contains `odd` number of elements, then there is only **one** middle element
- If array contains `even` number of elements, then there are **two** middle elements
- If array contains only **one** element, then that is the middle element
- If array contains only **two** elements, then both of them are middle elements
- If array is `empty`, then there is no middle element

Considering above use cases, I can find my middle element(s) from an array using the extension on array type:

```
extension Array {
    var middleElements: (first: Element, second: Element?)? {
        if count == 0 {
            return nil
        } else if count.isEven {
            // even number of elements
            let middleIndex = count / 2
            let element1 = self[middleIndex - 1]
            let element2 = self[middleIndex]
            return (element1, element2)
        } else {
            // odd number of elements
            let middleIndex = count / 2
            let element = self[middleIndex]
            return (element, nil)
        }
    }
}

// helper extension
extension Int {
    var isEven: Bool {
        return self % 2 == 0
    }
}
```

### Usage:

*Array with 3 elements:*

```
let array = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
if let first = array.middleElements?.first {
    print(first) // Prints Two
}
if let second = array.middleElements?.second {
    print(second)
}
```

*Array with 2 elements:*

```
let array = ["One", "Two"]
if let first = array.middleElements?.first {
    print(first) // Prints One
}
if let second = array.middleElements?.second {
    print(second) // Prints Two
}
```

*Array with 1 element:*

```
let array = ["One"]
if let first = array.middleElements?.first {
    print(first) // Prints One
}
if let second = array.middleElements?.second {
    print(second)
}
```

*Empty array:*

```
let array: [String] = []
if let first = array.middleElements?.first {
    print(first)
}
if let second = array.middleElements?.second {
    print(second)
}
// Prints nothing
```